# Android PackageManager getChangedPackages - Android 12

Tags: java, android, android-package-managers, android-12

We are trying to get a list of all updated packages using Android Package Manager [getChangedPackages](https://developer.android.google.cn/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#getChangedPackages(int)) function.

This is the code we use:

```
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ChangedPackages;
PackageManager pm;
pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
ChangedPackages changedPackages = pm.getChangedPackages(0);
```

This code works well on Android 10 & 11 and is detecting installed / updated / deleted packages.

However, the same code detects **only** deleted packages when running on Android 12 devices. We've installed some applications and those were not detected at all by the getChangedPackages application. Only after deleting the applications then the package names appeared in the list of changed packages returned from function.

We've also tried to use `changedPackages.getSequenceNumber();` or even `Settings.Global.getInt(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.BOOT_COUNT);` as the *from* parameter sent to getChangedPackages but with no success.

We couldn't find any documented changes that can explain this behavioral change.
[Android12 changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12)

Have you experienced similar thing or have any idea how it can be solved?
We will appreciate every piece of data or advice.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try adding QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission to manifest.
This issue might be related to packagemanager changes in newer android versions for privacy improvements. Im onto a similar issue for quite a while.